# Visual Studio 2017 the connection string could not be found in application settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dataset, xtrareport, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

For connection database and reading data, I am using a dataset which read connection string from Web.config file. Everything working in Visual Studio 2013. But when I opened this project in Visual Studio 2017, I can't configure. It errors:

> Unable to find connection string xxxx. the connection string could not be found in application settings or the data provider associated with the connection string could not be loaded

[image]

Comment: me too same problem; hope next VS version solve the problem..

Comment: still the problem exists.

Comment: Is there anything in the conversion/upgrade log upgrading the solution? When you open a solution in a new visual studio then it creates a log with warnings and errors if there are any. I think it is called upgradelog.htm and put besides the solution.

Comment: @Uwe no warning in the UpgradeLog.htm

Comment: Please, read this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08a48cad-619d-4421-b584-f2b5550ba6c5/dataset-designer-quotunable-to-find-connection-myconn-mysettings1-for-object-mysettingsquot?forum=winformsdatacontrols A common reason of this error is duplicated entry in web.config file.

Comment: @MaciejLos There is no duplicate entry. This has only happened after the upgrade

Comment: @EmanueleGreco Update the VS to 15.9. The problem fixed for me.

Comment: @Shereen thanks, this worked for me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the VS to 15.9. This will fix the existing problem

Answer (score 7):

Try to **update** your Visual Studio to 15.9 in the first place. And if it didn't fix the problem, try the following steps:

- Close the `DataSet` window with the error.
- Right click the `DataSet` in the solution explorer.
- Select "Open with…" from the context menu.
- Select "Source Code (Text) Editor" from the list and press the "OK"
  button.

> Near the top of the file, you'll see a element with several elements
>   within it. Most `DataSet` should only have one element. If you are
>   having trouble like I've described above, you'll have at least two and
>   one will be incorrect. Delete it or otherwise fix it, save the file
>   and reopen normally.

References:

https://blog.dmbcllc.com/unable-to-find-connectionfor-object-webconfig/

[Problem to update my dataSet designer : Unable to find connection 'ERMConnectionString (Settings)1'](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf0e950a-5232-4fff-b1c3-a35e9c10cd3d/problem-to-update-my-dataset-designer-unable-to-find-connection-ermconnectionstring-settings1?forum=csharpgeneral)

[Failed to load dataset because of the following error: Unable to find connection ...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfdfa2b9-57bc-42f8-b71b-a07388cb8618/failed-to-load-dataset-because-of-the-following-error-unable-to-find-connection-?forum=adodotnetdataset)

[Dataset Designer: "Unable to find connection MyConn (MySettings)1 for object 'MySettings'"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08a48cad-619d-4421-b584-f2b5550ba6c5/dataset-designer-quotunable-to-find-connection-myconn-mysettings1-for-object-mysettingsquot?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

[Unable to find connection 'MyConnName' for object 'Web.config' in Table Adapter configure Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101459/unable-to-find-connection-myconnname-for-object-web-config-in-table-adapter)

Comment: Update the VS to 15.9. The problem fixed for me

Answer (score 3):

This is a `TableAdapter` error. *TableAdapters provide communication between your application and a database*. Some people alleged that seems The **Visual Studio 15.8.x** no longer uses the connection string in the *web.config* while you may have not any problem in prior versions like 15.7.x.

Any way I believe you can **reproduce a working one** by using one of approaches listed in [How to: Save and edit connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-save-and-edit-connection-strings?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Update the VS to 15.9. The problem fixed for me