# Unable to modify DataSet in designer - can't seem to locate connection string

Tags: c#, ado.net, msdatasetgenerator

I have a `DataSet` I have been working with in an application that I have been building and modifying largely through the designer interface. I have had zero problems since the last change I made, and the application still runs and accesses / modifies the data in the `DataSet` with no problems.

Unfortunately, now when I try and make any sort of change through the designer, a message box is shown with the following message:

> Configure TableAdapter ExcelView failed. Unable to find connection
>   'EsNotesConnectionString' for object 'Settings'. The connection string
>   could not be found in the application settings, or the data provider
>   associated with the connection string could not be loaded.

Looking at the xsd generated by the designer, the `Settings` object and associated `EsNotesConnectionString` property seem to be pointed correctly by the following xsd element.

```
<Connection AppSettingsObjectName="Settings" AppSettingsPropertyName="ESNotesConnectionString" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="ESNotesConnectionString (Settings)" ParameterPrefix="@" PropertyReference="ApplicationSettings.ESNotes.Editor.Dataset.Properties.Settings.GlobalReference.Default.ESNotesConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I could not find an xsd element that points `Settings` or its connection property to a different location.

The connection string is located (and correct) in the Properties.Settings of the appropriate project as seen below:

[image: connection_str_in_properties]

The connection is successful when testing the connection through the Properties.Settings interface for connection strings, and the same user account can successfully access the database through other interfaces. Has anyone else had this problem? Why can't the `DataSet` designer find the connection string? I can in fact edit the `DataSet` by editing the code and xsd itself, but this is a huge pain compared to using the designer interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being embarrassingly simple. I was able to once again make edits in the designer by changing the `Connection` property of the appropriate `TableAdapter` (or stored procedure) to `(None)`, then back to its original connection. Note that this had to be done for each table or stored procedure I wished to make changes to through the designer. Don't ask me why this was necessary, but it fixed my problem.

Comment: I came to this solution after copying a DataSet from another Project in VS2019, using Project > Add Existing Item ...

It did end up having multiple Connection Strings in the Text Editor Access - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578441/2567114

I created a new connection to the new server via Project > Add New Data Source

Then selected that Connection string into the TableAdaptors of the copied DataSet